# How to implement scroll on WebElement on Selenium in Java?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, scroll

I have a scroll that is responsible to scroll a table on the page, not the whole page, so I cant use `window.scrollBy`

I've tried to find the scroll's container (I don't see a scroll specific object in the DOM) and use the following code:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse =  (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollBy(0,200);",scrollContainer);
```

(ScrollContainer is WebElement)

I'm getting the exception:

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: arguments[0].scrollBy is not a function

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: you should pass the VALUE of `arguments[0]`

Answer (score 0):

The method `HTMLElement.scrollBy` is not supported by all the browsers. Use `scrollLeft` or `scrollTop` instead:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse =  (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollTop += 200;", scrollContainer);
```

Comment: If there's no scrolling, then the element assigned to `scrollContainer` is not scrollable. A scrollable element usually has the CSS property `overflow` set to `scroll` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/overflow).

Comment: Working!! Thanks!